# abstracting data from huge file and exporting this data in excel

Tags: r, memory, export, limit

I have a huge data file with genotypic data. I want to extract certain data and export this data in excel at once. When I am running the code for abstracting the data, R wants to put this data in the Console window and I am then getting error messages that there is not enough memory space. Is there a way to tell R, not to put the extracted data in the Console window but export it instead in an excel file?

The code for abstracting the desired data is

```
subset(project, grepl("^UEBB018.*", pedigree_dhl) )
```

Comment: I'd be more inclined to help if you gave some indication that you've made a good faith effort to investigate R's many file writing functions, searched for things like "write xls file in R", and made some attempts based on what you find.

Comment: I know how to export data from R to other files. But whenever I run the code to substract the specific data, my computer crashes, so I am asking if anyone knows how to tell R in one step to export the  substracted data right away.

Comment: Frankly, it sounds like you are calling `subset` but not _assigning the result to anything_. If you're confused about assigning values to variables, you should start with a basic R manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a follow-up to @joran's comment:

```
 subfile <- subset(project, grepl("^UEBB018.*", pedigree_dhl) )
 write.csv(subfile, file="outUEBB018.csv")
```

<strike>My memory is that you need to do this in two steps because the first argument to write.csv is not evaluated,</strike> but my memory on such details is not great. (I use the help files a lot.) Ben's comment below is correct. You can do it in one step.

Comment: In my youth there was a TV advert: "Aren't you glad you use Dial, Don't you wish everyone did?"

Comment: I'd be surprised if `write.csv(subset(...),file="...")` didn't work (although of course I haven't tested it either). `subset()` is a little trickier in its internals, so it might be worth using `write.csv(project[grepl("^UEBB018.*",pedigree_dhl),],file="outUEBB018.csv")`

Comment: Since the answer worked, you should go ahead and 'accept' this answer (click on the check mark, I think)